# How could I find intersections in a string array with a variable number of elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection

I have a function that receives an array composed of numerical, comma separated strings as input, then finds the intersectional numbers in those strings and returns a string of similarly comma separated numbers, with no spaces, containing those intersections. If there are no intersections between the two elements, the function will return false.

What I want is to optimize the function so that it can work with a string array that may have more than just two elements. Is that possible? If so, could I have some sort of guideline of where to start looking for answers?

Currently, this is what I have.

```
function LocateIntersection(strArr) { 

  let arrHalf1 = strArr[0].split(", ");
  let arrHalf2 = strArr[1].split(", ");

  let interArr = arrHalf1.filter(value => arrHalf2.includes(value));

  let result = interArr.join();

  if (result) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little flawed, but it should meet your requirements

```js
function LocateIntersection(strArr) {
    const AllArrHalf = strArr.map((value) => value.split(', ')).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
    const lastArrHalf = AllArrHalf[AllArrHalf.length - 1];
    let interArr = [];

    AllArrHalf.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (index !== AllArrHalf.length - 1) {
            interArr.push(lastArrHalf.filter(value1 => value.includes(value1)))
        }
    })

    if (interArr.length > 1) {
        let result = interArr.map(value => value.join(', '));
        LocateIntersection(result);
    } else if (interArr.length === 1) {
        result = interArr.join();
        console.log(result);
    }
}

LocateIntersection(['a, b, c', 'a, b', 'a, b'])
```

Comment: If you want to get the ``result``, you have to define the ``result`` outside the function

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const intersection = (arr1, arr2) => { 
    return arr2.filter(element => arr1.includes(element));
}

const getIntersection = (stringArray, prevResult) => {
    const array1 = prevResult || stringArray[0].split(', ');
    const array2 = stringArray.shift().split(', ');
    const result = intersection(array1, array2);
    console.log(`result : `, result)
    if(result.length > 0 && stringArray.length > 0) {
        return getIntersection(stringArray, result);
    }
    return result;
}

const input = ['1, 2','1, 3, 3, 3','123, 222','1, 1, 1','1','3, 2, 3, 1'];
const result = getIntersection(input);
console.log('final Result:',result);
```